# My CSS changes on my app when it first loads

Tags: html, css, reactjs, search

I am currently developing a weather app, when the page loads the CSS is different from when you have searched a location, it appears on the top left. Here is a gif showing this.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk1Vn.jpg

Can anyone tell me why the image jumps when first searched but is transitioning smoothly after a couple of searches?

My code:

**CSS**

```css
html, body, #root {
    font: 0.9rem sans-serif;
    background: #0a1f44;
    color: #1e2432;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    width: auto;
}
    
.app.cold {
    background-image: url('./images/cold.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
    
.app.warm{
    background-image: url('./images/warm.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}
    
    
.search {
    outline: none;
    padding: 20px 7%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.85);
}
    
.city {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 40px 8%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    background: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.85);
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px 0px rgba(15, 15, 15, 0.404);
}
```

**APP.JS**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { fetchWeather } from './api/fetchWeather';
import './App.css';

const App = () => {
    const [query, setQuery] = useState('');
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

    const dateBuilder = (d) => {
        let months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
        let days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

        let day = days[d.getDay()];
        let date = d.getDate();
        let month = months[d.getMonth()];
        let year = d.getFullYear();

        return `${day} ${date} ${month} ${year}`

    }

    const search = async (e) => {
        if(e.key === 'Enter') {
            const data = await fetchWeather(query)
           
            setWeather(data);
            setQuery('');     
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className ={
            (typeof weather.main != "undefined") 
            ? ((weather.main.temp > 18) 
            ? 'app warm' : 
            'app cold') 
            : 'app'}>
        
            <input
            type="text"
            className="search"
            placeholder="Search... "
            value ={query}
            onChange={(e) => setQuery(e.target.value)}
            onKeyPress={search}
            />

            {weather.main && (
                <div className="city">
                    <h2 className="city-name">
                        <span>{weather.name}</span>
                        <sup>{weather.sys.country}</sup>
                    </h2>
                    <div className ="city-temp">
                        {Math.round(weather.main.temp)}
                        <sup>&deg;C</sup>
                        </div>
                        <div className="info">
                        <img className="city-icon" src={`https://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${weather.weather[0].icon}@2x.png`} alt= 
    {weather.weather[0].description} />
                        <p>{weather.weather[0].description}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )}
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you host this code on codesandbox, it would be easy to inspect the issue

Answer (score 0):

if you can host your code on any editor then it will be easy to inspect and solve.

For now as per my understanding you should use a wrapper class which will hold your cold and warm + search container div and that wrapper should have display: flex, align-items:center, justify-items:center etc. and the most important thing to have a min-height to wrapper. Because in app first view your container for cold & warm is not rendering into browser so there is no min-height to any parent class which will cause you layout hold in terms of height. As you your query search something you have divs with images etc. and then your layout looks fine.